# Python - How to do Async Requests With Delay?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have *n* APIs with an API limit of 1 request every 10 seconds. Snippet of the code below (imagine for simplicity that the other APIs look the same):

```
class API1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_limit_in_seconds = 10
        self.headers = {...}
        self.last_request_sent_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds = self.api_limit_in_seconds)
        self.urls = ["url1", "url2", ...]

    async def async_request(self, url, type_of_request):
        async with asyncio.Semaphore():
            await asyncio.sleep(0 if math.ceil((datetime.datetime.now() - self.last_request_sent_time).total_seconds()) > self.api_limit_in_seconds else self.api_limit_in_seconds - math.ceil((datetime.datetime.now() - self.last_request_sent_time).total_seconds()))
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers = self.headers) as session:
                async with session.request(type_of_request, url) as r:
                    result = await r.json()
                    self.last_request_sent_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                    return result

    async def post_requests(self):
        r = await asyncio.gather(*(self.async_request(url, "GET") for url in self.urls))
```

It could be argued that I don't need Async, as the requests library would be fast enough to handle one request every 10 seconds, however the APIs are related to each other, so it may happen that I either want to send a request to all the APIs as fast as possible, or that the result of one API would need to be sent to all the others.

The problem with requests is that, if I have 10 APIs and each non-concurrent call takes me (let's say) 1 second, it would take me 9 seconds to send the request to the 10th API.

I then tried to solve this with Async but I can't make the code below work as the below requests are still concurrent. How can I solve this? In short I need to:

- Send one request.
- Set the last_request_sent_time to the current time.
- Set a wait that waits the time necessary before the next request.
- Send a second request after the wait.

Comment: Your async workflow seems to be attempting to turn itself back into sync.

Comment: On a single API level that's true: with one call possible every 10 seconds, I don't need the speed of async. The problem is that a certain call from a certain API, blocks the calls of the other APIs (that have independent API limits) if I don't have an asynchronous way of sending requests with the other APIs

Comment: instead of trying to customize this, you could make use of an API rating library that could do that for you. One that will use an external redis will even take care of API limits if you have multiple workers for your script. This search: "python api rate limiter redis site:python.org " on google will bring you some nice options

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself. My example is actually working the only mistake is that I redefined the Semaphore every time in the `async_request()` function.

By putting the Semaphore in the `__init__` (Example: `self.sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)`) and changing `async with asyncio.Semaphore():` with `async with self.sem:` in the `async_request()` function, the code works as per my question.

The `1` I put in the Semaphore parameter should be the maximum amount of calls possible to the API in the time defined in `self.api_limit_in_seconds`